# Why does Platinum evaporate if left long enough?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

I have been reading into research relating to the redefining the 1 kg weight as the current Platinum-Iridium is becoming smaller. In this article, [here](http://us.mt.com/us/en/home/supportive_content/specific_overviews/WeighmatterKilogramArticle.html), it mentions that the original metal weight couldn't be pure Platinum as it evaporates over time. This article was referenced from 'The Scientist' which is a respected science magazine.

My questions are:

1. why does Platinum evaporate over time? As a (relatively soft) solid, I would have assumed it wouldn't lose particles due to evaporation, as the external environment is way below even the melting point of Platinum.
2. Is this not localised to just Platinum and other metals are included, indeed, will most solids evaporate over time?

Comment: A related counterintuitive fact is that for a gas in the limit of low pressure, the equilibrium state is one in which every atom is ionized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say the block of Platinum is in vacuum. For such low pressures, the melting point is not the same as the one in atmosphere: it becomes very close to a zero temperature. In other words, everything would tend to become gas under zero pressure.

Indeed, even for a solid in vacuum, atoms sometimes will escape due to fluctuations. It might condense back on the solid later on. This competition between evaporation and condensation leads to an equilibrium at a pressure equal to the [vapor pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure).

For a mixture, say Platinum+air, things are slightly different, but the idea is the same: atoms can escape the solid and condense later.

UPDATE:
Following Alexander's comment, I calculated that, at the maximum temperature where Pt is solid, 2000 K, there is still no significant evaporation inside a 1 m$^3$ volume: mass changing by $10^{-8}$. I used data from [here](http://www.platinummetalsreview.com/pdf/141-149-pmr-jul05.pdf%E2%80%8E) and an ideal gas law. So the evaporation does not seem to affect Pt at room temperature. Maybe chemical processes? That would be a question for chemistry.SE.

Comment: Yes, but what is the "leak rate" of Platinum at room temperature? I can't imagine that this is significant.

Comment: Although Pt is pretty much unreactive - could there be chemical reactions between Pt and atoms in the air?

Answer (score 3):

**In short** : It's not clear at all if Platinum **I**nternational **P**rototype of **K**ilogram (IPK) looses mass over time.

IPK is made from Platinum 90% and Iridium 10%. [Platinum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum) is mostly very stable, has good anti-corrosion and anti-oxidation properties in air. However, in air due to adhesion - absorbing of air molecules - IPK sample surface forms a thin film of *platinum dioxide*. This $\text{PtO}_2$ film layer can be removed by heating surface to about $400~^\circ C$, so called *cleaning* procedure of IPK and it's replicas over the world before comparing/measuring their masses.

Now, interesting part. Despite the cleaning procedure(s) after IPK mass comparison with it's replicas it was deduced that IPK copies increases relatives masses to the IPK over time. [BIPM (French Standards Bureau)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Prototype_of_the_Kilogram) has calculated that replicas augment their relative masses to IPK with a rate about $1~\mu \text{g/year}$. Here's is a chart how IPK copies accumulates mass over time :

[image]

So either :

- IPK original looses mass over time, compared to it's replicas OR
- IPK replicas accumulates mass better than IPK original sample.

There is no accepted consensus what's going on, because there's too less measurement data available, burden of definition- because IPK original is always "1 kg" and you can't verify it's mass completely in absolute terms, because measurement scales are calibrated upon it. Also an interesting fact, that BIPM has established *globally* platinum dioxide surface layer removal procedure just in 1994 year. Before that other standards committees (like NIST, etc) had their own versions of 1 kg replicas cleaning procedure. That's why we may see that different IPK replicas mass accumulation curves deviates from each other over time (no common mass augmentation rate between IPK copies).

Due to this conundrum, 1 kg definition was again re-defined not to depend on specific instance IPK sample. Now definition is based upon equality :

$$ mc^2 = h \nu \tag 1$$, so expressing everything in SI units and using Caesium atom base transition frequency $\Delta \nu_{Cs}$

we can conclude that 1 kg is :

$$ 1 kg = \frac {c^2}{h \Delta \nu_{Cs}}\left[C^0\right] \cdot \frac {h \Delta \nu_{Cs}}{c^2} = 1.475 521 400 × 10^{40} ~ \frac {h \Delta \nu_{Cs}}{c^2} \tag 2$$,

Note that $C^0$ indicates that first multiplication term units of $kg^{-1}$ are being omitted for making a unit-less constant.

Answer (score 2):

The fun stuff is that even if a material has e.g. an average temperature of room temperature, some of its atoms have a higher temperature (because of quantum laws). Some of these atoms have such a high temperature that they can evaporate (which cools down the whole body). But when the body gets reheated (because the room is an infinite amount of heat storage), some atoms are again too fast (have too high temperature) and evaporate.
This is the reason why every material looses weight over time...

Comment: Temperature is a bulk property, not a property of individual particles. Some atoms have high *kinetic energies*.

Comment: Yes, I know, I am not always correct with english termini...

Comment: It's also nothing to do with quantum laws, it's because of the thermal motion of the atoms. Also, it isn't true that "every material loses weight over time", because condensation also happens.

Comment: The main question is though, would Pt be able to lose a measurable amount of mass?

Comment: Yes, I think so (as you can see in the article mentioned above...)